How to monitor sensor reliability in ROS2?
I'm building a mobile robot with multiple standard sensors (camera, imu, etc.) and have a general question about how to monitor the sensors' reliability.
More specifically, I am using a camera along with the realsense-ros package to capture point cloud data for obstacle detection. However, I’ve noticed that occasionally the point cloud data stops publishing, which is a concern since obstacle detection is a safety-critical application.
I’ve considered using QoS deadline settings to monitor the continuity of the data stream. However, most hardware-interface packages do not allow overriding singular QoS properties, but only allow to select one of the general qos_profiles.
Therefore, I'm wondering what are the best practices for handling and verifying the reliability of sensors in ROS2?
Thank you in advance for your help!

One common option is to use the standard diagnostics framework and let the camera publish its status (sane drivers do so). Then you can have a general watchdog that just monitors the overall diagnostics status and when there's an error, it can e.g. stop the robot.

Thank you for the answer.
I have also considered using the diagnostics framework, but I think topic delays are not generally monitored there. The problem is that delayed messages or outages can occur due to a multitude of reasons, such as sensor failures but also network failures. Ideally, I would like to catch any failure related to the sensor pipeline (data measurement + data transmittal) that causes my obstacle detection problems.
